# Time delay detection in time series

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, meteorology

I'm trying to align series of weather data. I have two temperature and pressure sensor which in some time periods has been shifted by some time.

Example data with offset equal to -600min
[image: Example data with offset equal to 10h]

I need to detect periods when the delay occurs and shift it so the time series will be better aligned to each other.

I tried windowed cross correlation on the raw data between sensors but it shows a lot of noise and the change point of the delay is strongly dependent on the window size.

Time delay (offset) in minutes with 24h window
[image: Time delay (offset) in minutes with 24h window]

I was thinking of detection of the change point of the cross correlation and then doing the cross correlation on the bigger chunks of the data so the value will be more stable in this periods.

Do you have any idea how to find the delays or at least make cross-correlation less varying through the time without loosing the exact change point?

EDIT:
I tried calculating cross correlation in 3 different window sizes - 24h, 1W, 2W and joining it with median. The result for full data set is below

Delay result in minutes for full data set.
[image: Offset result]

From beginning to 10.2013 the value should be equal -600.

From 10.2013 to 03.2016 it should be equal -300.

From 03.2016 it should be -600.

Do you have some idea how to make data not varying so much?

Comment: Welcome to CV! As far a I understand the shift is normally zero but at some random times it can switch to a different value (e.g. 600 min). Do you have any prior information on the switch point process and the possible value of the shift between two switches?

Comment: Yes normally the shift is zero and it can shift in any time. There is no information about switch point and the possible value except that it can by any value from 10, 20,... 990, 1000min in both sides (10min is data resolution).

Comment: I was also thinking of using the temperature sensor for the detection since it should have the daily peak in similar time. I have one temperature sensor which I can rely the time is true and the second can be shifted, if the peaks will be in different time I would shift it.

Comment: I'm confused... if there is a sudden 600 min time delay that wasn't there before, shouldn't there either be a gap in one signal or 600 mins of data are simply missing?

Comment: @jhin the pressure_2 on the first plot is missing the beginning of the data and it is started with the delay already.

Comment: This is  a change point detection problem. The "shift" process could be considered as a (hidden) Markov process with a few transitions by year (plot #3). Maybe the number of states (201) could be reduced. You seem to have two bivariate observed  time series: one shifted and one non-shifted. If so a crude model for the non-shifted series could be used.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. I resolved the issue I will write it down later.